# Creating tables with accessible content

Tags: android, sqlite

i am new on android coding, lets describe what i want to do, i made an sqlite database and a table in my App, which has 5 elements: (Lecture name, class day, class time, place, exam time)
the problem is, how can i make an layout like this:

[view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01F7o.png)

which on the right side there are times, and on the top there are days, i want to each of the table contents be accessible, i mean that if someone, added a table row in my database with this Contents: (math,sunday,11:00,uni,test)
then the name of the math, go in sun,11:00

any idea of how can i do this?
thanks

Comment: You can create a custom BaseAdapter, and populate your data in your view. And, whenever you are adding an entry in your database. You can refetch that data from database to a ArrayList and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `adapter`. Google each step and you get how to do. Ask me if any troubles.

Comment: @Darpan thanks for your help, But there is one problem, As I searched, the custom Base Adapter is for list view, is that right? but i want a table, exactly like what im shown in this picture:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/01F7o.png
is it possible to do something like this with a custom BaseAdapter?

Comment: Lets say you have seven days, and say your school works from 8 - 3 pm. So you will be having 7*7 = 49 fields only. No more number of boxes will be in your tableView?

Comment: @Darpan yes thats exactly right dear Darpan, thats all I need to create in my App, there is no more boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is not plug and play, you may need to make some modifications as well here.
Create a table layout - (I have created only two rows, so make other rows as well -

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mon08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#dcdcdc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Row 2 column 1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tue08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 2"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wed08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thu08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fri08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sat08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sun08"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</TableRow>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mon09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#dcdcdc"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Row 2 column 1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tue09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#d3d3d3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 2"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wed09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thu09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fri09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sat09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sun09"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#cac9c9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Row 2 column 3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</TableRow>
```

Then, Let's say you fetched data from your database as (Mon 11 am  math)

So using this function get the resourceID -

```
private int getResourceID (String name){
Resources resources = YourActivity.this.getResources();
final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", 
   YourActivity.this.getPackageName());
return resourceId;
}
```

And to set data -

```
private void setData(){
//get day in first three letters like mon, tue and time slots as 08, 09 so it will give mon08, so point to that textview and set your subject.
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(getResourceID(day+time));
textView.setText(yourSubject);//set the subject in here.
}
```